# How to run existing task scheduler's task using Python?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I created a task in my Windows 10 Task Scheduler. I was wondering whether it is possible to run the task using Python. I know it is possible to run the task using CMD ([How to run existing windows 7 task using command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632489/how-to-run-existing-windows-7-task-using-command-prompt)) but can I somehow do it using Python.